# Apartment security system service light is on

Tags: security

I live in an apartment that came with a security system.  I've never used the system, but the system has been acting up lately.  The system seems to be activating for no apparent reason (producing a high pitch tone), and the service light is on.  The tone goes away when I press Cancel.

I called management, but they said that they don't actually maintain the security systems in my unit.  My unit came with this security system, but I never got any information about it, and the management changed hands while I've lived here.

All the advice I've found so far involves knowing the model of the system, but all I can tell is the GE logo.  There is a screw in the bottom, but I don't really want to open the magic box.  I also haven't figured out what the plastic slide-out on the left is for.

[image: Security system]

I want to fix the problem or call someone to get it fixed.  How can I figure out what system this is?  Alternatively, who should I call to get service for this system?  A local home security provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing there's a worn out battery in the panel or one of the sensors and that's causing it to act up.

You have a couple of options:

- Call a local home security company and have them either fix the unit, replace it, or deactivate it.  They might do it for free if you sign a service contract.
- Deactivate the panel yourself.  Remove the panel from the wall, disconnect the power cord (and a phone cord if there is one), then open the panel and disconnect the internal battery.  (To disconnect the power cord, you might have to open up the panel or unplug a mysterious looking plug from a nearby outlet.)

Comment: I disconnected the unit from power, and I didn't find a backup battery.  This was helpful.  I'll wait to see if any other issues come up from leaving the system disconnected.

Comment: It's possible that it doesn't have a backup battery or that the battery no longer functions well enough to power the unit.  Either way, if it's not making noise, you should be okay.